# Using a Static Library of Custom View Controllers with Storyboards

Tags: ios

As in 
[using iOS static library common view controller in storyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11123179/using-ios-static-library-common-view-controller-in-storyboard)

I am trying to use a common static library across multiple projects. IB or rather ny Storyboard throws the error:

Unknown class IETInitialViewController in Interface Builder file.
2013-10-04 12:07:12.998

because it is unable to locate the custom view controller in a linked static library. 
Does anyone have a decent way of solving this?  I know this was asked a year ago but I wonder if anyone since then has found a way.

Answer (score 0):

For one, I recommend that you use the universal framework.  What you are looking for is an "embedded framework" under this system.

https://github.com/kstenerud/iOS-Universal-Framework

It will give you a reference to the .xib file or storyboard as you need it.  It also gives you the much prettier framework looking icon as opposed to the ugly brown box one.

It's also just fantastic and handles so much of the set up for you, so that your compiled library automatically works on the simulator and the iPhone.